# HAproxy as s reverse

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have VM f.e  192.168.2.5 Lan Ip  where we have 2 IIS sites: www.site1.com, www.site2.com

I have 1 WAN IP  in pfsense where HAProxy Instaled  f.e  71.71.71.71

I want to configure a reverse proxy with SSL

Blockquote

if someone types site1 should be redirected inside 192.168.2.5 with relevant www.site1.com 
if someone types site2.com should be redirected also to 192.168.2.5 with relevant www.site2.com

I am nube and please help us for the configuration 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will depend on whether both the IIS sites are hosted on the same port. If yes, you will need to add the appropriate host header before routing to the backend.

For a sample config, please use this reference:

https://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name/

Also use this link on how to add header, if required:

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/7-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/#add-a-header

Answer (score 0):

Thank you i will read

both sites in the VM are hosted in 80 port

one more question, there is possibilities one host in 8443 and another in 6443 and in the front add an appropriate route to the specific sites
but when clients types in the web site1.com, the external port should not be shown